# Publish generated NuGet Packages with TFS 2015 RC

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-server, tfs-2015

I am trying to set up an automatic build.vnext process for TFS 2015. This build process contains one *Visual Studio Build* build step, in which a `.nupkg` package file is created in the build agent's `bin/Debug` and `bin/Release` directories.

I have a private NuGet-Server installed on the same server as the build agents are running on. I want to copy the generated `.nupkg` files from the bin-directories to my NuGet-Server's package-source-folder (say `C:\Packages`).

How can I do this with TFS 2015 Build.Vnext/Preview?

Edit:
I can easily copy all build output from the agents to the package folder by configuring the *Visual Studio Build* options "Copy to Staging Folder" Search Pattern to `**/bin/*`. This copies the folders `myProject\bin\Debug` and `myProject\bin\Release` folders and their contents to the package folder.

If I specify e.g. `**/bin/**/*.nupkg` or similar, nothing is copied, even though a respective *.nupkg file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem:

1. Under Options set *Copy to Staging Folder* of the *Visual Studio
   Build*-Configuration to true.
2. Use the search pattern `**\bin*`
3. Add a *Command Line* utility definition.
4. Let it execute `C:\YourPathTo\nuget.exe` with the arguments `push C:\YourStagingPath**\bin***.nupkg -s [YourServer] [YourAPIKey]`

Done.